# Job calls procedure not exactly same interval, which is defined in schedule

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, job-scheduling

I have table with `TIMESTAMP` type column.

I have procedure which inserts into this table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t2
  (dt)
  VALUES
  (LOCALTIMESTAMP);
END;
```

Then create schedule:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name => 'my_job',
    job_type => 'stored_procedure',
    job_action => 'my_procedure',
    start_date => '2016-10-31 17:01:01',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
    end_date => '2016-11-30 17:01:01',
    auto_drop => FALSE
  );
END;

EXEC dbms_scheduler.ENABLE('my_job');
```

Then `SELECT * FROM t2 ORDER BY dt`

Results are:

```
2016-10-31 17:40:13
2016-10-31 17:40:21
2016-10-31 17:40:34
2016-10-31 17:40:42
2016-10-31 17:40:54
```

As you see, `INTERVAL` for schedule is 10 second, but difference between inserts (rows) are sometimes 8 second, sometimes 13 second, sometimes 12 second and so on.

Question: why is so not exactly that interval between procedure calls, which is defined in schedule?

Comment: I think that in scheduler you're scheduling time of job start, not how long it will take to actually insert the value. It could depend on db performance or other variables.

Comment: @massko -- If first job starts at `17:40:13`, then why second starts after 8 seconds (`17:40:21`), third starts after 13 seconds (`17:40:34`), when I have interval 10 second? This is the question.

Comment: I know, but I think you're looking into table where date was inserted, not when job started. Look into all_scheduler_job_run_details table to see the job run details, maybe it will help.

Comment: @massko --  Thank you, I did not know about it. it seems reason is that `ACTUAL_START_DATE` not matches `REQ_START_DATE`